Complex parameterizations of real-valued distributions
Suppose we have some random variable $X$ that takes values in $\mathbb{R}^n$, parameterized by $\theta \in \Theta$ where the parameter space $\Theta$ is finite-dimensional.
In almost all statistical applications, we take $\Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and conduct inference on real-valued parameters.
However, there’s one case that I’m aware of - McCullagh’s parameterization of the Cauchy distribution - where taking $\Theta \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ yields some interesting insights about the distribution.
I’m curious if there are other interesting examples of this approach that people have come across in their work.
To clarify, I’m specifically interested in cases where parametric models with support on the reals are endowed with a complex-valued parameter space, and something statistically interesting shows up as a result - as opposed to cases where it’s mathematically convenient to work in the complex plane as part of a proof, or nonparametric examples involving complex-valued functional parameters.
